# Enable/Disable onclick using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I want to re-enable a disabled `onclick`. I am using:

```
$('#id_'+id).prop("onclick", null);
```

to disable the `onclick`, but when clicking once again on the button I want to re-enable the `onclick` again. How do I do that?

Comment: What is `$('#id_'+id)`? Is it a form element?

Comment: nope $('#id_'+id) is not a form element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like others said use

```
$(id).off('click')
```

in Another way

your Question is not proper,

From your question i get so,

```
<input type="Button" id="test" >
<script>

    $('#test').on('click',function(){
        if($(this).attr('class') == '_enable'){
            alert(' its working');
        }
        $(this).addClass('_enable');
    });
</script>
```

first time it won't get the alert from next on wards u ll get the Alert!!!!

if want to disable again then remove that **_enable** class!!!!